# How does the golang interface convert arrays?

Tags: go

```
package main
    func test() {
        arr := []string{
            "1","2","3",
        }
        inter := ArrayToInterface(arr)
        // interface to array
    }

    func ArrayToInterface(t interface{}) interface{} {
        return t
    }
```

The array is passed to a function and converted to interface type. Now how to convert it to array

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. 1. Interfaces don't convert anything. 2. What is the purpose of `ArrayToInterface` which does nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `type assertion`

```
for _, i := range inter.([]string){
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```